# Passing value of one Auto Complete extender to another auto complete extender using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using two auto complete extender in my asp .Net form with vb. I want to pass value of one Auto Complete extender to another auto complete extender using jQuery and also that should be browser compatible.

Comment: what is an autocomplete extender? u mean the autocomeplete, ui? secondly visual basic???thirdly put up some code so ppl can look at what you have and maybe give us some ideas :)

Comment: This question does not meet more-recently formed guidelines for Stack Overflow questions. I am going to try to close it (either Needs Focus or Needs Clarity).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guesssing you want to pass the value from one autocomplete box to another autocomplete box? That will not work - autocomplete is only trigered on key down (**I think....**)

jQuery (UI) is cross-browser compatible.

jQuery is independant to programming language, so it doesn't matter if you use C#, VB.Net, PHP or other programming langauges / scripts.

Comment: @vebby, no problem. Just remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem / question, and up-vote if you found the answer usefull :)

Comment: I am still working on it.Have not got any result yet,so not accepted yet.And I am not a registered user so can't up-vote.Thank You Sir.